# Error when tring to retrieve AuthorizationGroups from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory, .net-6.0

I'm trying to go through about 11K users and retrieve their authorization Groups from Active Directory using `UserPrincipal`  (C#, .NET 6):

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = up.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

I've noticed that I'm getting the following error:

> An error (5) occurred

on some of the users.

Later on I've noticed that I'm getting the same error, but on different users each run.

Furthermore, `up.GetGroups()` works every time.

I assume `GetAuthorizationGroups` takes longer, and by activating it on 11K users one by one I'm getting a timeout or something in that area.

Is there anyway to make it more efficient? Am I in the right direction?

I'll add that this process should take no longer than 30 minutes, so I used `Parallel.Foreach` on a bulk of 20 users.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you searched error 5 to know what it means? Do you notice the error happening during certain hours of the day? Could there be system maintenance or other competing accesses to AD going on during that time?

Comment: @TawabWakil I understood that error 5 is related to security, but because the i dont get it on the same users, and I've seen other posts that link this error to timeouts - i figured it happens because the AD is busy

my proccess run for 11K users so I also assume it is the one responsible.

Comment: If you can't figure out the root cause, you might have to live with it and put a try/catch and some retry logic around `GetAuthorizationGroups`. It would be a good idea to do this even if it was working perfectly, because you cannot control how AD will behave. I have personally seen cases where calls to AD throw random exceptions that don't make sense. In that case, I wait a few seconds and try again and it usually works. If it doesn't, I give up after a while and log an error or alert the user.